# Convert centimeters to inches using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need a JavaScript function to convert CM to IN. I have been using the following:

```js
function toFeet(n) {
  var realFeet = ((n*0.393700) / 12);
  var feet = Math.floor(realFeet);
  var inches = Math.round(10*((realFeet - feet) * 12)) / 10;
  return feet + "&prime;" + inches + '&Prime;';
}

console.log(toFeet(100));
```

The catch is it converts 100cm into 3'3". I only deal in CM (australia) but from checking on conversion sites it appears this is wrong.

Any advice?

Comment: 3'3" means 3 feet and 3 inches, wich is correct.

Comment: this might help:: http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/inchconvert.shtml

Comment: 100cm is 39.37 inches, which rounds to 39 inches, which is 3 feet, 3 inches, so it looks like your function works correctly.

Comment: 1" = 2.54 cm... 1' = 12". So 100 cm = 100 / 2.54 = 39.37" = ~3'3"

Comment: ok ok - thankyou... I did see 39.37 inches but didn't understand it... thankyou :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no problem

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct and gives the right result.

I would change it in the following way, so I am sure I do not lose precision using an approximate number for the conversion. This may be useless in your case, but sometimes could come into play (e.g. calculating distances on maps).

```
var realFeet = n / 30.48; // = 12 * 2.54
```

Comment: In general, the precision loss caused by approximating the number is irrelevant compared to the precision loss you have when displaying the number in ft'in" anyways. You would not measure a distance on a map in inch anyway (and perhaps even feet), but more likely in yards or miles.

Comment: You are probably right for all practical purposes. But if I approximate to the 5th digit in the conversion parameter and I convert something like 10000 miles I could be wrong by about 1 mile.